# Which is best simple Gaussian blur or FFT of Gaussian blur for sigma=20?

Tags: algorithm, gpu

I'm making a program to blur a 16 bit grayscale image in CUDA.

In my program, if I use a Gaussian blur function with sigma = 20 or 30, it takes a lot of time, while it is fast with sigma = 2.0 or 3.0.

I've read in some web site that Guaussian blur with FFT is good for large kernel size or large sigma value:

- Is It really true ?
- Which algorithm should I use: simple Gaussian blur or Gaussian blur with FFT ?

My code for Guassian Blur is below. In my code , is there something wrong or not ?

enter code here

```
__global__ 
void gaussian_blur(
    unsigned short* const       blurredChannel,                     // return value: blurred channel (either red, green, or blue)
    const unsigned short* const inputChannel,                       // red, green, or blue channel from the original image
    int                         rows, 
    int                         cols,
    const float* const          filterWeight,                       // gaussian filter weights. The weights look like a bell shape.
    int                         filterWidth                         // number of pixels in x and y directions for calculating average blurring
    )
{
    int r           =  blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;       // current row
    int c           =  blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;       // current column


    if ((r >= rows) || (c >= cols))
    {
        return;
    }

    int           half   = filterWidth / 2;
    float         blur   = 0.f;                             // will contained blurred value
    int           width  = cols - 1;
    int           height = rows - 1;

    for (int i = -half; i <= half; ++i)                 // rows
    {
        for (int j = -half; j <= half; ++j)             // columns
        {
            // Clamp filter to the image border
            int     h       = min(max(r + i, 0), height);
            int     w       = min(max(c + j, 0), width);

            // Blur is a product of current pixel value and weight of that pixel.
            // Remember that sum of all weights equals to 1, so we are averaging sum of all pixels by their weight.
            int     idx     = w + cols * h;                                         // current pixel index
            float   pixel   = static_cast<float>(inputChannel[idx]);

                    idx     = (i + half) * filterWidth + j + half;
            float   weight  = filterWeight[idx];

            blur += pixel * weight;
        }
    }

    blurredChannel[c + r * cols] = static_cast<unsigned short>(blur);
}





void createFilter(float *gKernel,double sigma,int radius)
{

    double r, s = 2.0 * sigma * sigma;

    // sum is for normalization
    double sum = 0.0;

    // generate 9*9 kernel
    int m=0;
    for (int x = -radius; x <= radius; x++)
    {
        for(int y = -radius; y <= radius; y++)
        {
            r = std::sqrtf(x*x + y*y);
            gKernel[m] = (exp(-(r*r)/s))/(3.14 * s);
            sum += gKernel[m];
            m++;
        }
    }
 m=0;
    // normalize the Kernel
    for(int i = 0; i < (radius*2 +1); ++i)
        for(int j = 0; j < (radius*2 +1); ++j)
            gKernel[m++] /= sum;


}


int main()
{

    cudaError_t cudaStatus;
    const int size =81;
    float gKernel[size];

    float *dev_p=0;
    cudaStatus =  cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_p, size * sizeof(float));
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMemcpy failed!");
    }
    createFilter(gKernel,20.0,4);

    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(dev_p, gKernel, size* sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMemcpy failed!");
    }

    /*  i read image Buffere in unsigned short that code is not added here ,becouse it is large , and copy image data of buffere from host to device*/

    /* So, suppose i have unsigned short *d_img which contain image data */

    cudaMalloc( (void**)&d_img, length* sizeof(unsigned short));
    cudaMalloc( (void**)&d_blur_img, length* sizeof(unsigned short));

    static const int BLOCK_WIDTH = 32;
    int image_width=1580.0,image_height=1050.0;

    int x = static_cast<int>(ceilf(static_cast<float>(image_width) / BLOCK_WIDTH));
    int y = static_cast<int>(ceilf(static_cast<float>((image_height) ) / BLOCK_WIDTH));

    const dim3 grid (x, y, 1);                              // number of blocks
    const dim3 block(BLOCK_WIDTH, BLOCK_WIDTH, 1);  

    gaussian_blur<<<grid,block>>>(d_blur_img,d_img,1050.0,1580.0,dev_p,9.0);

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    /* after bluring image i will copied buffer from Device to Host and free gpu memory */
    cudaFree(d_img);
    cudaFree(d_blur_img);
    cudaFree(dev_p);


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not true gaussian blur but if you don't need it to be perfect then maybe this is useful to you: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42192/Fast-Image-Blurring-with-CUDA

Comment: Also, partitioned fft convolution is generally faster for larger kernels

Comment: @Pete Generally what would be the size of guassian kerenal for sigma =20 or 30 or mor ?

Comment: @Pete Because if i make kernel size 41*41 or more then my code takes time more than 1 sec. but i want to finish bluring method in <0.1 sec. so have you any idea about that ?

Comment: Gaussian blur is a separable filter. By using two passes (vertical + horizontal) you reduce the complexity of your algo from N^2 to N (one order of magnitude).

Comment: Isn't the width of the gaussian distribution essentially infinite?  You need to pick a kernel width where the significance drops below a given level (e.g. 1%).  It should be possible to calculate this but I don;t know how off the top of my head.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: **both** algorithms are **good** with respect to **image blurring**, so feel free to pick the best (fastest) one for your use case.

*Kernel size* and *sigma value* are directly correlated: the greater the sigma, the larger the kernel (and thus the more operations-per-pixel to get the final result).
If you implemented a naive convolution, then you should try a *separable convolution* implementation instead; it will reduce the computation time by an order of magnitude already.

Now some more insight: they implement *almost* the same Gaussian blurring operation. Why *almost* ? It's because taking the FFT of an image does implicitly periodize it. Hence, at the border of the image, the convolution kernel sees an image that has been wrapped around its edge. This is called **circular convolution** (because of the wrapping). On the other hand, Gaussian blur implements a simple **linear convolution**.

Comment: i will add my code of Kernel and blur a 16 bit grayscale image using that kerenal. I s it correct or not ? and whatis the size of kerenel for sigma wiil be 30 ?

Comment: In my code i fixed size of kernel is 9*9, but what would be the size of kernel for sigma =20 or 30(means large sigma value) ?

Comment: Your Gaussian kernel needs to be large enough to contain most significant blurring coefficients. See http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#Mat%20getGaussianKernel%28int%20ksize,%20double%20sigma,%20int%20ktype%29 for a typical way of doing it.

Comment: Generally what would be the size of guassian kerenal for sigma =20 or 30 or more ?

Comment: Rule of thumb: Gaussian coefficients vanish at +/- 3*sigma. Sigma = 20 implies 3*sigma = 60, so the kernel width should be around 120 pixels). Close to what you can find by inverting OpenCV's formula (gives 141 pix).